# Dynamically update a number field by summing the values of the other number fields on the same page

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've been struggling to dynamically update a number field in my Apex application with the sum of values from the other number fields on the same page. The page contains a questionnaire with 6 questions that have predefined answers, along with a predefined number score for each answer. At the bottom of the page I have a number field labeled "Score" that I want to be updated depending on the answers chosen.

I've went ahead and created a dynamic action that is supposed to update a number field named P3_SCORE.

The example I've been trying to get to work adds two of the items at the moment, number field item P3_SELFCARE and P3_MOBILITY.

```
BEGIN
return :P3_SELFCARE + P3_MOBILITY;
END;
```

I keep getting errors with my PL/SQL Function Body.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what the errors you're getting are, but don't you want

```
BEGIN 
  return :P3_SELFCARE + :P3_MOBILITY; 
END;
```